# What people love about/love the most about X (company)

Tags: grammar

I writing reviews of people and I want to start off by saying the above sentence. But I'm confused. Should it be love about or love the most about?

Comment: It's up to you.

Comment: So either one is correct?

Comment: It's a matter of what "tone" you're trying to convey.